# Kusto query: How to summarize by column(s), then check if certain records are in the group

Tags: azure-log-analytics, azure-data-explorer, kql

I'm fairly new to Kusto and need to query for certain records in Log analytics.

Problem: Need to summarize by column `ActivityId`, then check if a list of `RunbookNames` (another column name) are within the group. I want all activityids that has Foo AND Bar. If it does not contain both then it doesn't satisfy criteria.

Something analogous to SQL query, we have `GROUP BY` then `HAVING` clause.

Any idea?

**Sample Data**:

| ActivityId | RunbookName | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5271D9E9 | Foo | State 2, Status 1 |
| 5271D9E9 | Foo | State 2, Status 1 |
| 5271D9E9 | Bar | State 2, Status 3 |
| 394B044 | Fooey | State 2, Status 1 |
| 394B044 | Dooey | State 2, Status 1 |
| D94321B | Dooey | State 2, Status 1 |
| 9E4371A | Foo | State 2, Status 1 |

**Expected Results**:

| ActivityId | RunbookName | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5271D9E9 | Foo | State 2, Status 1 |
| 5271D9E9 | Foo | State 2, Status 1 |
| 5271D9E9 | Bar | State 2, Status 3 |

Comment: Can you give the smallest possible sample of what your data looks like and what you'd expect the query to produce?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

judging by the given input and output, and your clarification in the comment, the following query could give you a direction.

```
let RunbookNames = dynamic("Foo", "Bar");
T
| SUMMARIZE r = make_set(RunbookName) by ActivityId
| where array_length(set_intersect(r, RunbookNames)) == array_length(RunbookNames)
| mv-expand RunbookName = r
```

Comment: The aggregation I'm looking for is to group the ActivityId and check if the group contains exactly the amount of Runbooks I'm looking for. (E.g. "Foo","Bar"). You filtered it down to ActivityId == "5271D9E9" but assume that there is 100+ that satisfied the criteria in which you cannot just eye ball each and everyone.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification (it was completely missing in the question as it was originally written). I've updated the reply

Comment: Thanks Yoni. The make_set helped a lot here. I found some issues with set_intersect filter mainly that I received some Runbooks within the set such as "Foo","Dooey" which incorrectly satisfies array_length. I ended up using multiple conditions to check if the set contains exactly what I'm looking for: RunbookName contains "Foo" and RunbookName contains "Bar"  and array_length(r) == 2